# What does "c/o" or "co" mean on the Diablo 3 trade chat?

Tags: diablo-iii, terminology

I've seen several times that people offer goods for sale on the Diablo 3 trade chat and add the letters "co" or "c/o" what do they mean by it?

From the decisions it seems to be some kind of auction because the messages usually go like:

> WTS [something] 50k c/o pst with offers
>
> WTS [something] 100k c/o pst with offers
>
> WTS [something] 150k c/o pst with offers
>
> [someting] 200k c/o going once
>
> [someting] 200k c/o going twice
>
> [someting] 200k c/o sold

What do they mean exactly, and what does the abbreviation stand for?

Comment: Cash only would be my guess but I've never seen it before

Comment: Another good acronym to know is **BO**, for **Buyout (price)**.  Also, WTS (want to sell) and WTB (want to buy).

Comment: b/o is another alternative for Buyout, and WTT (want to trade) is a very common term as well for most MMOs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C/O or CO means 'current offer'.

This refers to either the current price at which the seller is offering the desired item, or the highest bid thus far from another party interested in purchasing the desired item.

Comment: Also, a 'BIN' may be mentioned, i.e. *Buy It Now* (buyout) price

Comment: Alternatively, they may use BO, also for Buyout.